# Cypress Error: Max -14876746378 should be greater than min 0

Tags: cypress, faker, faker.js

I am so sorry I am a beginner in programming as well as automation.
I keep getting this error during my test runs. I was trying to create a random date using @faker-js/faker and I was able to do that earlier. I was even able to proceed up to the part where i check the checkboxes.

Here is my code:

```
beforeEach(() => {
        cy.visit("xxx")
        cy.get("input[type='text']").type("Test@admin.com")
        cy.get("input[type='password']").type("Test2023!")
        cy.get("button[type='submit']").click()
        cy.xpath("//span[normalize-space()='Cycle Calendar']").click()
        //cy.wait(2000)
        cy.xpath("//span[normalize-space()='Add New Cycle Calendar']").click()
        //cy.wait(1000)
    })



    it("Receiving from the mobiler", () => {
        //generate random start and end dates for the date picker
        const startDate = faker.date.future(    )
        const endDate = faker.date.between(startDate, faker.date.future())

        //Format date to yyyy-mm-dd
        const formattedStartDate = dayjs(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        const formattedEndDate = dayjs(endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')

        //click start date
        cy.get("input[placeholder='Start date']").click({force: true}).type(formattedStartDate)
        cy.get("input[placeholder='End date']").click({force: true}).type(formattedEndDate)

        //checkboxes MON-SAT
        cy.xpath("(//input[@type='checkbox'])[1]").check({force: true})
        cy.xpath("(//input[@type='checkbox'])[2]").check({force: true})
        cy.xpath("(//input[@type='checkbox'])[3]").check({force: true})
        cy.xpath("(//input[@type='checkbox'])[4]").check({force: true})
        cy.xpath("(//input[@type='checkbox'])[5]").check({force: true})
        cy.xpath("(//input[@type='checkbox'])[6]").check({force: true})
        cy.xpath("(//input[@type='checkbox'])[7]").check({force: true})

        const validDays = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
        const validDaysCount = countValidDaysInRange(formattedStartDate, formattedEndDate, validDays)
        cy.log('Number of valid days between ${formattedStartDate} and ${formattedEndDate}: ${validDaysCount}')
        //cy.get("button[type='submit']").click()
        //cy.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Continue')]").click()

        function countValidDaysInRange(formattedStartDate, formattedEndDate, valid) {
            const start = dayjs(formattedStartDate)
            const end = dayjs(formattedEndDate)
            let count = 0
        
            for (let current = start; current <= end; current.add(1,'day')) {
                if (validDays.includes(current.format('dddd'))){
                    count++
                }
            }}

    })
```

Here is the error message I was getting in Cypress:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aL6I.png)